# Can I ask questions at Stack Overflow in Russian written in English? Могу ли я задавать вопросы на Stack Overflow на русском на английском?

Tags: поддержка, перевод-содержимого

I don't know Russian, but I know there are many talented Russian-speaking people here, who are probably friendly and open minded. Can I ask questions in English, at "Stack Overflow in Russian"?

Я не знаю русского, но знаю, что здесь много талантливых русскоязычных людей, которые, наверное, дружелюбны и открыты. Могу ли я задавать вопросы на английском в «Stack Overflow на русском»?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, but no. It is not allowed to ask questions in a language other than Russian on our website. Such questions will be closed, but they will be reopened once the translation is done.

I can suggest you to try to use Google Translate for this purpose. If your questions are not entirely correct, but in Russian, they will simply be edited out.

You can also chat in ru.SO chat where English is allowed.

> Извините, но нет. На нашем сайте запрещено задавать вопросы не на
> русском. Такие вопросы будут закрыты, но они будут снова открыты, если
> их перевели.
>
> Я могу предложить вам попробовать использовать  Google Translate. Если
> ваши вопросы будут не совсем правильными, но на русском языке они
> будут просто отредактированы.
>
> Также вы можете поговорить в чате ru.SO, где разрешен английский.

Comment: Разве в чате английский разрешён? Вроде раньше был отдельный чат для английского, но подозреваю, что он замёрз.

Comment: @Qwertiy Был такой чат? Прикольно я как раз подумывал сделать такой сам. Ну а про разрешен,  я так понимаю да т.к. 1) чаты могут относиться с сайту, но не являются его частью 2) мне никто ничего не сказал когда я вел беседы с разными людьми из StackExchange [здесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115386/smokey-on-ru-so) по-английски.

Comment: Ну если тот, с кем общаешься, знает только английский, то естественно ok.

Comment: [Разморозил.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45075/)

Comment: @Qwertiy https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355861/may-i-speak-english-in-the-chat-related-to-a-localized-site

Answer (score 2):

If some community member knows English and can understand questions AND writes answers - most likely there are already contributing en.SO too. Therefore, there is no point in asking question in English on this site (besides, this is clearly prohibited by the rules).

Если некоторый участник знает английский язык и способен понять вопрос и написать ответ на нём - скорее всего он уже присутствует на основном сайте. А потому нет никакого смысла задавать вопросы на английском на этом сайте (к тому же это явно запрещено правилами).

Comment: Не-а, я понимаю английский могу задать вопрос и ответить. Но на en.SO практически ничего не делаю.